# Android: Smart way to customize AlertDialog while preserving default theme

Tags: android

I would like to show an AlertDialog with 2 lines of text as its message.  The 2nd line of text should be of a smaller font size than the first, be underlined, and I would like to be notified when it is clicked.  Also, I would like the AlertDialog to look similar to one constructed by calling AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage.

The custom layout can be accomplished with the below code, but the result looks very different then dialogs created by using AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage.  The two images attached are dialogs created by this code, and by calling AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage, respectively.

Any suggestions for how to use my custom layout while preserving the default theme of the AlertDialog?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("first line");

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText("second line");
    tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tv1.getTextSize() * .8f);
    tv2.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(this);

    layout.addView(tv1);
    layout.addView(tv2);
    builder.setView(layout);

    builder.show();
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT

Ok, I was unable to produce a reasonable result with the below code. The problem with this is that the textsize of the second line is hard coded to 12 dips, but I would like it to actually be proportionally smaller than the text size of the first line - maybe 80% of the first line's textsize.  Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

(Also, determining when the underlined portion of the text is clicked will be a bit ugly, but I think I can figure that out)

```
    String text1 = "First line\n\n";
    String text2 = "Second line";

    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(text1 + text2);
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), text1.length(), text1.length() + text2.length(), 0);
    content.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(12, true), text1.length(), text1.length() + text2.length(), 0);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(content);
    builder.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest define an activity as being of theme Dialog and then you can design that activity to look like whatever you want and it will display as a dialog (with the Activity beneath grayed out, just as you want)...

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyDialog"
            android:label="@string/app_name"                 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.my.package.DIALOG" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Note that the only thing I'm adding here that you don't already have in your manifest is the theme attribute in the activity node.

Comment: I do want to use an AlertDialog though (if possible), because I will also add positive/negative buttons to it and would like the button bar  default decorations which AlertDialog provides.

Comment: You can add whatever buttons you want to your own activity! I'm not sure that what you're looking to do (modify some aspect of the stock dialog) is doable. I believe it's not.

Comment: The AlertDialog gives a default appearance for the buttons if you add them by calling AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton, etc.  The appearance is different depending on the OS build, so it will be difficult to recreate in a custom Activity.  Similarly, the default appearance of text in AletDialogs varies according to device build.  Which is why I would like to try to use a customized AlertDialog, if possible.

Comment: but by the same token, if you start customizing the displayed elements in the dialog (such as the text fields) you're just as likely to blow right out of whatever theme is set as the default. If you build your own activity and just use Button (without setting any color on the text or the background) then it will, in fact, utilize whatever theme is default on the device. In the above code I use Theme.Halo, but that's arbitrary, you can just set it to Dialog and then it will fall back on whatever the device prefers.

Comment: Did you see my edit using spannables? This seems like a good way to cusotmze without blowing away the default.  The problem is that AlertDialog has a default layout, as well as default theme properties; its not just a matter ob making the buttons the same style as the default, it also involves laying them out in the same way.